# Unable to cast object of type AnonymousType To System.Data.DataRowView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datarow, datarowview

I am beginner in WPF. I am trying to read Datagrid Selected Items with DataRow/DataRowView. My code is following--

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRowView row in dgDocument.SelectedItems)
  {
    txtPhotoIDNo.Text = row["PhotoIdNumber"].ToString();
  }
```

but I am facing the following error--

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   '<>f__AnonymousTypeb`11[System.String,System.Byte,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Byte[],System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.String]'
>   to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'."

When I am trying with following Way, that works fine-

```
(dgDocument.SelectedCells[2].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
```

The problem is when I required to add a new column/change the datagrid column position, I required to change index for entire assigned value. To cover this problem, I want to assign value with the above mentioned way with column Name.

Comment: The `DataGrid` control has nothing to do with `System.Data` / `DataTable` etc.  The `SelectedItems` property contains the actual objects you have added to the grid (which in this case seem to be anonymous types).  You should look into data binding - you shouldn't be trying to set the text directly like this.

Comment: Please! Give me an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of SelectedItems list is going to be of the type that is bound to your DataGrid. So for example if I have a property List DataSource in my codebehind and I bind this list to be the ItemsSource of the data grid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource={Binding DataSource) />
```

the grid.SelectedItems will return me a List of strings.

In your case the ItemsSource of the DataGrid is bound to some kind of anonymous type. While I would generally discourage from using anonymous types in this particular case, the workaround for you would be the following:

```
foreach (dynamic item in dgDocument.SelectedItems)
  {
    txtPhotoIDNo.Text = Convert.ToString(item.???);
  }
```

You need to substitute ??? with the name of the property from the anonymous class that contains the data you are looking to put into txtPhotoIDNo.

Answer (score 0):

At Last I found my Problem. That is two Values of my SelectedItems was null.For this reason Key value pair does not prepare perfectly. The following code work perfectly.

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRowView row in dgDocument.SelectedItems)
  {
    txtPhotoIDNo.Text = row["PhotoIdNumber"].ToString();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (dynamic row in dgBarDetails.ItemsSource)
 { 
  myList.Add(row);
 }
```

in my case row is an object of my class used to populate ItemsSource. It can be an int or string or whatever you have in ItemsSource